# `ping -a` hangs for ~5 seconds while `nslookup` doesn't

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ping

**Configuration:**

- Windows 7
- NetBIOS over TCP is OFF

**Observations:**

- `ping -a <ip-address>` hangs for ~5 seconds before failing reverse lookup (and using ip address instead)
- any application using `gethostbyaddr()` in attempt to reverse lookup ip address has same problem
- `nslookup <ip-address>` returns almost instantly with `blah-blah: Non-existent domain`

**Questions:**

- Why this happens? I assume due to NetBIOS broadcast messages (final step of reverse lookup), but switching `NetBIOS over TCP` off was supposed to disable this step, isn't it?
- How to change my configuration to get rid of this delay with existing applications?
- What function(s) application need to use to avoid this delay (i.e. to behave as `nslookup` instead of `ping`)?

Answer (score 0):

There are different steps in the name resolution process.

These mains steps are (in order) :

- Looking in the host file
- Using Domain Name Service
- Using alternative name resolution protocole (NBNS and/or LLMNR)

Source : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order-dae00cc9-7e9c-c0cc-8360-477b99cb978a

At least one of this step take lots of time.

Some possible problems :

- Big host file or unreadable host file
- Application waiting for DNS Answer
- Application waiting for NBNS/LLMNR answer

The configuration to apply to get rid of this delay depend of the step creating this problem.

I advise you to use a sniffer like Wireshark to see what happen when your ping is running in order to know what protocol are used for the resolution.

Comment: I can't see anything in Wireshark: dns request/response -> 5s pause -> ARP request for target address (it is in same subnet as me) -> ICMP pings. `procmon`ing "ping.exe" -- there is a 5 sec gap (in terms of system calls). IPv6 is off. I'll try to debug this, but it is mystery...

Comment: Huh... I found a `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` adapter on my machine -- the moment I switched off NetBIOS in it (or disabled adapter) -- ping started behaving! Wireshark showed zero traffic on that adapter and yet it's presence caused these 5 sec delays...

Comment: So it seems that your Virtual Box adapter is used instead of your legitimate adapter. You could try to increase the metric of the Virtual Box adapter in order to let the other be used.

Comment: I just disabled `NetBIOS over TCP` in it. I wonder why Wireshark didn't see any traffic on it?